# How to add functionality to the official Take Photo Button of Android Phones?

Tags: android

I need to add functionality to that button, but i dont know the name of the button, and I dont know how to give it functionality.

Does someone know what to do?

SOLVED:

```
    mSurfaceView.requestFocus();
    mSurfaceView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    boolean keyManaged=false;
    switch(keyCode)
    {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA:
            mCamera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);  
            keyManaged=true;
            break;
    }
    return keyManaged;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It show up as `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA` in a [KeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/KeyListener.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you need this while your app is active you can simply register `OnKeyListener` and check for `KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN` event.

OTOH if you want to be notified when your app is not active then you need to register to receive a Broadcast: http://suhassiddarth.blogspot.com/2010/12/programming-hardware-button-android.html